# Bash shell script to prompt user for input with a (CLI GUI) dialog box

Tags: bash, input, prompt

Hi and first of all thanks to all those that give helpful answers/pointers!!

I'm writing a Bash script that at times may need to ask the user for input.  I'm looking for a tool to present a input box (think GUI pop up message box) at runlevel 3 (no X Windows) that provides a selection list and option for manual input.  It should provide a radio button next to each option.

For example if it were asking the user for a name it would present a list like this

---

(*) Johnny

( ) Ben

( ) Hillary.

( ) `<manual input>`

---

Where the `<manual input>` line would be a text box to allow the user to enter free text.
The output should be to standard out and should be the name e.g. "Hillary".

In summary the requirements are:

1) It should pop up and be a bright color to grab the user's attention.  Flat text is not suitable

2) Preferably allow selection using the cursor or a mouse

3) Provide a radio button selection list

4) Also allow for free text input

5) Write the selection to standard out

6) I don't want to wipe the status/log messages already on the screen

Bash's read command is not "flashy" enough, it doesn't grab the user's attention.

The tool [dialog](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) wipes the text already on the screen as it re-draws the whole screen and does not allow for both a selection list and a free text input box in one screen.

Thanks again

MC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as sugested above dialog commands would work

Create a dialog with --keep-tite to keep your screen after input and using --checklist makes it posible to have radio select box. 
Place all the answers into a array and have a while loop echo each array item.

${#arrayName[@]}  --> number of items in array or number of selection
${arrayName[@]}  -->  outputs all array items

```
#!/bin/bash

result() {
i=0
echo there are ${#arrayName[@]} options selected
while (( i < ${#arrayName[@]} ))
do
  echo $i ${arrayName[$i]} 
  i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done
}

cmd=(dialog --separate-output --keep-tite --checklist "Select options:" 22 76 4)
options=(1 "Johnny" off
         2 "Ben" off
         3 "Hillary" off
         4 "User Input" off
)

choice=$("${cmd[@]}" "${options[@]}" 2>&1 > /dev/tty )

for answer in $choice
do
# make decsion 
case $answer in
    1) 
       arrayNum=${#arrayName[@]}  # arrayNum is the amount of items in arrayName 
       arrayName[$arrayNum]="Johnny" # if selected put Johnny in arrayName
       ;;
    2) 
       arrayNum=${#arrayName[@]}  # If johnny is selected ${#arrayName[@]} outputs 1 if not selected 0 
       arrayName[$arrayNum]="Ben" # If selected add to array
       ;;
    3) 
       arrayNum=${#arrayName[@]}
       arrayName[$arrayNum]="Hillary"
       ;;
    4) # If User Input is selected create an new dialog inputbox 

    user_input=$(\
    dialog --keep-tite --title "Enter Your Name" \
        --inputbox "Enter name:" 8 40 \
    3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- \
    )
       arrayNum=${#arrayName[@]}
       arrayName[$arrayNum]="$user_input"
       ;;
esac
done
result
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, answers containing only code are not suited for stack overflow...

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 ways. YMMV

- Use [Zenity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity) (probably disqualified since you don't have X).
- Use [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/) - As for the thing on the screen disappearing, structure your script to use dialog completely and present even the informational text inside the widgets. It also has a --stdout option to direct it's output to the standard output so that it persists. Whiptail is a dialog replacement which I believe is lighter.
- Use [tput](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html) and manually move the cursor, draw colours etc. to make your dialogue box stand out. This is tedious and error prone.

I don't like bright colours and things especially for normal selections. I'd much prefer a subdued `read`. However, if you want to do this, I'd recommend the second approach. Your application should either use a widget toolkit or not use it. Don't try to make it do both. It's not worth the trouble.

Comment: Lighter?  perhaps not - as noted in the dialog [manual](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h3-WHIPTAIL).